# Dynamics CRM option set

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I am new to Dynamics CRM so please excuse me for the newbie question xD

I managed to create an option set field with 2 possibilities:

1. Scheme 1
2. Scheme 2

Does anyone have an idea how when a particular possibility is picked, a list of custom based fields will appear in the form? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly you want certain fields to appear/disappear according to the choice selected in the option set.
The way I see this working is by implementing a Javascript on the onChange event of the option set. you can do this from the 'Form Properties' when changing the layout of the form.
Below is a link showing some examples of possible useful commands that might help you:

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/01/14/crm-2011-useful-javascript-tidbits/

You can put your custom fields in a custom tab and then hide/disable it according to the value in the option set.

If you have any further problems feel free to ask :)

I hope this helps :)
Gdluck

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable working in Visual Studio, I highly recommend installing [the Developer Toolkit](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmnontechnical/b/c5insightblog/archive/2011/11/29/managing-web-resources-and-plug-ins-with-the-crm-developer-toolkit.aspx) (You can find the .msi \tools\developertoolkit - [download it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004)).  It will allow you to develop JScript with some syntax highlighting and intellisense and makes source control and deployment a snap.